# AWS S3 Add paramters to signed url

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

i use django-storages to store static and private files in a s3 bucket.

For a few files i need to pass parameters in the url because the requested html file generate dynamic content with these parameters.

For example:

```
https://example-static-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/header.html?name=Example&site=2
```

With static files this works very well.

But if i fetch the signed url for a private file with django-storages and add the parameters i get an error:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
...
</Error>
```

How can i add parameters to a signed url with django-storages?

Answer (score -1):

S3 stores static objects, you can't modify them with signed URLs. Think of S3 objects as files in a filesystem: they have a path and a name and you can get their contents, but they are a dumb container for data.

Similarly, you can not have a static/header.html to become different based on the parameters of the call. You can upload a file and you can download it, that's it.

Comment: That is not correct. For my static files this works very well! My html file read the url parameters with javascript and change the content based on the parameters. But is there a way to do that with presigned urls?

Comment: You mean you read the query parameters with Javascript running in the browser?

Comment: Yes. I use pdfkit, i think that render the page with a browser implementation.

Comment: You might try to add a hash fragment (#name=Example) which might works and the browser does not send with the request. The problem with signed URLs is that all the query parameters affect the signature, that's why you see this error message. You can use CloudFront to get rid of the param going to S3, but that's a bit more involved.